# Removing Classnames from Ember view

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ember.js, view, extends

I am trying to create view that has functionality described in a view in am extending, but with different class names.  What is happening is the ExpTypesView classes are ['nav','nav-pills'] **and** ['nav','nav-tabs'].  How do i set it so they **replace** the classnames set in NavView?

```
Resume.NavView = Em.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  classNames: ['nav','nav-tabs'],
  currentPathDidChange: function(){
    Ember.run.next( this, function() {
      $("ul li:has(>a.active)").addClass('active');
      $("ul li:not(:has(>a.active))").removeClass('active');
   }); 
  }.observes('controller.currentPath')
});
Resume.ExpTypesView = Resume.NavView.extend({
  classNames:['nav','nav-pills']
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an `Ember.View`, `classNames` is a [concatenated property](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#property_concatenatedProperties) so properties that you add will be concatenated with the super class values.

You can use `classNameBindings` to set the type in both the super class and the descendant.

```
App.NavView = Em.View.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  classNames: ['nav'],
  classNameBindings: ['type'],
  type: 'nav-tabs',
  currentPathDidChange: function(){
    Ember.run.next( this, function() {
      $("ul li:has(>a.active)").addClass('active');
      $("ul li:not(:has(>a.active))").removeClass('active');
   }); 
  }.observes('controller.currentPath')
});

App.ExpTypesView = App.NavView.extend({
  type: 'nav-pills',
});
```

This makes the classes `class="ember-view nav nav-tabs"` and `class="ember-view nav nav-pills"`.

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/orunin/1/edit)

Answer (score 2):

This dirty little workaround is giving me what I want, but if you know a better way or any resource that explains this please let me know!

```
Resume.ExpTypesView = Resume.NavView.extend({
  //classNames:['nav','nav-pills'],
  init: function(){
    this.set('classNames', ['nav','nav-pills']);
  }
});
```