# Ember remove parent class from child component

Tags: ember.js

I have an addon component that is wrapping a component from a different addon:

```
// parent-addon/addon/components/parent-component.js
import Component from '@ember/component';
import layout from '../templates/components/parent-component';

export default Component.extend({
  layout,
  classNames: ['parent']
});

// child-addon/addon/components/child-component.js
import Parent from 'parent-addon/components/parent-component';
import layout from '../templates/components/child-component';

export default Parent.extend({
  layout,
});

// child-addon/addon/templates/components/child-component.hbs
{{#parent-component}}
  Hello
{{/parent-component}}
```

Because classNames are concatenated, the wrapper div for the child component contains the "parent" class, e.g.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="parent">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to remove the "parent" class from the classNames of the child component? I don't have access to the parent addon so I can't change any of its code.

Comment: Why do you extend the parent class? Probably you shouldn't do this.

Comment: @Lux I wanted to inherit the parent's default values for the parent component's properties

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512115/removing-classnames-from-ember-view/%22this%20post%22), had to do

```
// child-addon/addon/components/child-component.js
import Parent from 'parent-addon/components/parent-component';
import layout from '../templates/components/child-component';

export default Parent.extend({
  layout,
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.set('classNames', []);
  }
});
```